# Python: Formatting text to specific column

Tags: python, string-formatting

I would like to format some text to the [protein data bank file format](http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html).  Basically what I need to do is start the text in specific columns.  Right now I'm doing the formatting using `ljust` and `rjust` but I feel like there should be some magic function that I could use give a word and in what column it should start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

If my Statckoverflow searching failed, please point me in that direction.

Comment: show what you have and the formatting you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how one might format a "Coordinate Record Description" using [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
CRD='{r:<6}{a:>9.3f}{b:>9.3f}{c:>9.3f}{alpha:7.2f}{beta:7.2f}{gamma:7.2f} {sp:<11}{z:>4}'

data=dict(r='CRYST1',a=117,b=15.0,c=39,alpha=90,beta=90,gamma=90,sp='P 21 21 21',z=8)
print(CRD.format(**data))

# CRYST1  117.000   15.000   39.000  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 21 21 21    8
```

The format specifier `CRD` is interpreted this way:

`{r:<6}` tells `format` to string-interpolate the value of `str(r)`, left justified, with width=6.

`{a:>9.3f}` tells `format` to string-interpolate the float value of `a`, right justified, with total width 9 and 3 digits after the decimal point.

The complete description of how the format specified works is given [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You can use string "format" function with alignment. http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec
Example with columns you can find in source codes to the 'Programming in Python 3: A Complete Introduction to the Python Language' by Mark Summerfield, file print_unicode.py